# What icon represents social media?

Tags: icon

I have a website I'm working on that uses 7 social media websites.

Rather than plaster them on the website and take up valuable screen real estate, I would like one icon that can float and, when clicked, a menu scrolls out which will contain all of the above icons.

For the mobile version (sub 480px), it's not a problem since the menu is hidden behind a menu icon which slides in. But for the tablet and desktop version, I would like to add a "social media" icon somewhere in the flow (as opposed to only in the footer).

What would you use to describe **"social media"**? I was at first thinking of using a share icon (which apparently is not a standard ([see this article](http://www.fastcodesign.com/3031872/why-isnt-there-a-standard-share-button)).

But then, we're not really sharing like in the days of Digg and Delicious. What we are really doing is **"connecting"** with people via social media? Is this a more proper term / concept?

Should I use a connect icon as opposed to a social icon to represent social media?

Comment: A person standing aside from a larger group and clutching a smartphone? (Which is kind of ironic, come to think of it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest either placing a few on a larger icon as shown below.

[image]

You could also go with a more generic icon with some sort of networking theme like the one shown below.

[image]

A lot of apps, such as youtube, use a 'share' icon which may cover what you are wanting.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The last one is a very common icon for "sharing". There are many variations of it, like a human icon is used instead of one point or there are more smaller joints.

Answer (score 1):

I think in cases like this it's best to follow what most users will find standard... So the share icon you see on most sites probably makes sense.

Personally though, I've been more inclined recently to leave off sharing buttons as they become more embedded at os level. On a mobile and modern desktops you can share directly through the os, with the benefit of it opening in app rather than taking to one of those share pages that you may or may not be logged into.

Answer (score 1):

The share icon would be the most common uses.
If you have questions like this try typing social icon on sites like Dribbble and see what the results are.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do when i'm in the situation of dealing with 7-8 Social Media icons is ill put the 3 most important (facebook, twitter, LinkedIn) and then make a dropdown menu after that where ill put the rest. The 3 most important social media of course depends on which business you are doing it for.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. If you want to know more about the site, please see [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!